# Event Hub :: Serialization operation failed due to unsupported type System.Byte[]

Tags: serialization, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am using the Azure Function Event Hub trigger to get the data from one  (source) Event Hub to another (target) Event Hub.

Some messages are flowing and some message are failing with error:

> Serialization operation failed due to unsupported type System.Byte[]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add some (relevant) source code as it's very hard answering your question in its current form. Explain what you tried and why that didn't work. Please refer to [ask]. On-topic: did you take a look at the [event replication tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-federation-replicator-functions)?

Comment: Were the events in the source Event Hub published using Kakfa, by chance?

Comment: @rickvdbosch, I am net to stack overflow so please excuse my ignorance. I am trying to put the source code but unfortunately the comment section is limited to number of characters

Comment: Jesse Squire - Yes, the source event hub is published using Kakfa. Because of x-dynatrace property is enabled in source side i am getting the header. Can I strip the properties of source in azure function?

Comment: namespace Ingestion
{public static class EventCopy
{
[FunctionName("EventCopy")]
public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("sourceeventhub", Connection = "Source_connectionstring")] EventData[] events,
[EventHub("targeteventhub", Connection = "targetconnectionstring")] IAsyncCollector<EventData> outputEvents, ILogger log)
{foreach (EventData eventData in events)
{try{
// send the message
await outputEvents.AddAsync(eventData);
}